# Action script server socket in mxml

Tags: actionscript-3, sockets

Can we write a server socket in mxml application and client socket in java? If so please give me an example.Give me some urls to implement this.I am new to Action script.So far i know that server socket will exist on air applications but i have to implement in mxml.

---

@Pascal Le Merrer This is my code for Action script server:

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.events.ServerSocketConnectEvent;
    import flash.net.ServerSocket;
    import flash.net.Socket;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFieldType;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;

    public class AsSocket extends Sprite
    {
        private var serverSocket:ServerSocket = new ServerSocket();
        private var clientSocket:Socket;

        private var localIP:String="0.0.0.0";
        private var localPort:int=8888;
        private var logField:TextField;
        private var message:TextField;

        public function AsSocket()
        {
            setupUI();
            bind();
        }

        private function onConnect( event:ServerSocketConnectEvent ):void
        {
            clientSocket = event.socket;
            clientSocket.addEventListener( ProgressEvent.SOCKET_DATA, onClientSocketData );
            log( "Connection from " + clientSocket.remoteAddress + ":" + clientSocket.remotePort );
        }

        private function onClientSocketData( event:ProgressEvent ):void
        {
            var buffer:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
            clientSocket.readBytes( buffer, 0, clientSocket.bytesAvailable );
            log( "Received: " + buffer.toString() );
        }

        private function bind():void
        {
            serverSocket.bind( localPort, localIP);
            serverSocket.addEventListener( ServerSocketConnectEvent.CONNECT, onConnect );
            serverSocket.listen();
            log( "Bound to: " + serverSocket.localAddress + ":" + serverSocket.localPort );
        }

        private function send( event:Event ):void
        {
            try
            {
                if( clientSocket != null && clientSocket.connected )
                {

                    clientSocket.writeUTF("Hii client");
                    clientSocket.flush(); 
                    log( "Sent message to " + clientSocket.remoteAddress + ":" + clientSocket.remotePort );
                }
                else log("No socket connection.");
            }
            catch ( error:Error )
            {
                log( error.message );
            }
        }

        private function log( text:String ):void
        {
            logField.appendText( text + "\n" );
            logField.scrollV = logField.maxScrollV;
            trace( text );
        }

        private function setupUI():void
        {
            message = createTextField( 10, 85, "Message", "Hii." );
            createTextButton( 170, 110, "Send", send );
            logField = createTextField( 10, 135, "Log", "", false, 200 )

            this.stage.nativeWindow.activate();
        }

        private function createTextField( x:int, y:int, label:String, defaultValue:String = '', editable:Boolean = true, height:int = 20 ):TextField
        {
            var labelField:TextField = new TextField();
            labelField.text = label;
            labelField.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
            labelField.width = 100;
            labelField.x = x;
            labelField.y = y;

            var input:TextField = new TextField();
            input.text = defaultValue;
            input.type = TextFieldType.INPUT;
            input.border = editable;
            input.selectable = editable;
            input.width = 280;
            input.height = height;
            input.x = x + labelField.width;
            input.y = y;

            this.addChild( labelField );
            this.addChild( input );

            return input;
        }

        private function createTextButton( x:int, y:int, label:String, clickHandler:Function ):TextField
        {
            var button:TextField = new TextField();
            button.htmlText = "<u><b>" + label + "</b></u>";
            button.type = TextFieldType.DYNAMIC;
            button.selectable = false;
            button.width = 180;
            button.x = x;
            button.y = y;
            button.addEventListener( MouseEvent.CLICK, clickHandler );

            this.addChild( button );
            return button;
        }        
    }
}
```

This code will not work on flex. I need to create a Air application to execute the above program but in flex project it will not compile please help me to do this
this is my code for java client:

```
package org.sample;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.net.SocketAddress;

public class ClientConnect {

    Socket socket = new Socket();


    ClientConnect() {
        String ipaddr = "0.0.0.0";
        SocketAddress sadd = new InetSocketAddress(ipaddr, 8888);
        try {
            socket.connect(sadd);
            socket.setKeepAlive(true);
            BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            writer.write("Hii server");
            writer.flush();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));
            clientRead(reader);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    void clientRead(BufferedReader reader) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                System.out.println("str" +  reader.readLine());
            }  catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        new ClientConnect();
    }
}
```

This is properly sending a string and receiving from java to action script

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this in MXML. It must be some Actionscript (that may be included in the script tag of a MXML file).

Look at [Adobe's documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/ServerSocket.html) for more.

Comment: you mean <fx:script>.even i'm ready to do it in <fx:script> can u give me any examples how to do it in <fx:script>

Comment: There is an example of creating a server in the link I gave, at the bottom of the page. And Yes, I mean a fx:script tag.

Comment: I have seen that example but it has worked for Adobe AIR not in fx:script.I created a java client and able to send a msg from java to Air class but i want for fx:script.Correct me if i'm wrong